# Returning data from task Django+Celery

Tags: django, celery

I'm new to Django and Celery. So what I'm trying to do is return data after it has been queried via the corresponding models object in a task.

tasks.py

```
from celery.decorators import task
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from .views_api_utils import *
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response


@task(name="get_all")
def get_all():
    dummies = Dummy.objects.all()
    return dummies
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def dummy_list_all(request):
    """
    list all dummy objects
    """
    if request.method == "GET":
        dummies = get_all.delay()
        serializer = DummySerializer(dummies, many=True)
        return Response(dummies, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The issue at hand is that I keep getting this error `TypeError: Object of type AsyncResult is not JSON serializable`.

Advise?

Comment: First of all remove celery i don't think u need celery here. Only used celery if result of  celery task not intercept your current running task or result don't matter in running task. ex: Sending email , sending notification or task that take long time and store result for future need.

Comment: or if you still want to use celery configure celery with `CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"`

Comment: @Meet you're right. Implementing a celery task to retrieve objects in this case is foolish. Thanks for the insight.